# Julia: can I run doctests without `makedocs`?

Tags: testing, julia

I am starting a Julia module and prefer to use only doctests and to skip documentation at this stage. The Julia [doctest documentation](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/doctests/index.html) says that `makedocs` can run doctests:

> Doctesting can be disabled by setting the makedocs keyword `doctest = false.`

It mentions no other method of running doctests. Does Julia offer any other way to run doctests similar to Python's `import doctest` and `doctest.testmod()`?

*Note:* Here is an example function:

````
"""
month_to_quarter(date::Date)

Returns the date corresponding to the first day of the quarter enclosing date

#Examples
```jldoctest
julia> Date(1990, 1, 1) == month_to_quarter(Date(1990, 2, 1))
true
julia> Date(1990, 1, 1) == month_to_quarter(Date(1990, 1, 1))
true
julia> Date(1990, 1, 1) == month_to_quarter(Date(1990, 2, 25))
true
```
"""
function month_to_quarter(date::Date)
    new_month = 1 + 3 * floor((Dates.month(date) - 1) / 3)
    return Date(Dates.year(date), new_month, 1)
end
````

Comment: No, that is not possible at the moment, but we have something like that in mind for future versions of `Documenter.jl`. I would like to point out though, that it is very easy to setup a simple document environment and just run the doctests with `makedocs` even if you are not planning to deploy the generated documentation.

Comment: Yes, and I posted a complete setup in [this other thread about missing doc-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768111/julia-documenter-missing-docstring/51207534#51207534). @fredrikekre do you want to post the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

No, that is not possible at the moment, but we have something like that in mind for future versions of `Documenter.jl`. I would like to point out though, that it is very easy to setup a simple document environment and just run the doctests with `makedocs` even if you are not planning to deploy the generated documentation. For a simple setup see e.g. this comment: [Julia Documenter: missing docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768111/julia-documenter-missing-docstring/51207534#51207534)

Answer (score 4):

For the record, [this is now supported](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/doctests/#Doctesting-as-Part-of-Testing).  Just add this to `runtests.jl`:

```
using Test, Documenter, MyPackage
doctest(MyPackage)
```

Note that if you have a separate `Project.toml` in your `test` directory, you'll need to `add Documenter`.  Also, if you have setup code in your `docs/make.jl` file, you'll need to copy it over and put it before the call to `doctest`.