# Julia Documenter: missing docstring

Tags: julia

I have a Julia module file with a function, a doc-string, and a doc-test. I load it and the doc-string shows in the Julia help, but Documenter.jl cannot find the doc-string.

An example module file, `src/my_module.jl`, is:

````
module my_module

"""
    add(x, y)

Dummy function

# Examples
```jldoctest
julia> add(1, 2)
3
```
"""
function add(x::Number, y::Number)
    return x + y
end

end
````

The make file `docs/make.jl` is:

```
using Documenter, my_module

makedocs(
    modules = [my_module],
    format = :html,
    sitename = "my_module.jl",
    authors = "unknown",
    doctest = true
)
```

The ouptut of `include("src/my_module.jl")`, then `?`, then `my_module.add`, shows that the Julia REPL found the docstring:

```
help?> my_module.add
  add(x, y)

  Dummy function

     Examples
    ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> add(1, 2)
  3
```

The output of `include("docs/make.jl")` shows that `Documenter` did not:

```
Documenter: setting up build directory.
Documenter: expanding markdown templates.
Documenter: building cross-references.
Documenter: running document checks.
 > checking for missing docstrings.
 !! 1 docstring potentially missing:

    my_module.add :: Tuple{Number,Number}

 > running doctests.
 > checking footnote links.
Documenter: populating indices.
Documenter: rendering document.
```

How come the Julia REPL finds the docstring and not Documenter?

*Notes*: I ran `Pkg.update()` before running the code. `Documenter` has version `0.18.0`, Julia has version `0.6.3`.

Comment: What does your `index.md` contain? I think your problem is that you don't include the docstring in the manual, i.e. in a `@docs` block or `@autodocs` block. See the manual: https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/syntax/#@docs-block-1

Comment: Also I think that non-exported names are not found by Documenter...? At least not with default settings?

Comment: @George Datseris: by default exported and non-exported methods are included: "To include only the exported names from the modules listed in Modules use Private = false. In a similar way Public = false can be used to only show the unexported names. By default both of these are set to true so that all names will be shown." Link [here](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/syntax/#@autodocs-block-1).

Comment: @fredrikekre: Yes, my `index.md` needed to include `@autodocs`. I also needed `@meta`, as suggested [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/doctest-error/6366). `index.md` now has two blocks in triple backquotes: `@meta; CurrentModule = my_module; DocTestSetup = quote; using my_module; end;` and `@autodocs; Modules = [my_module]`, where the colons stand for new lines. I also need to either export the function under test or prefix it with the module name. It all works now. Do you want to answer the question or should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of @fredrikekre, I was missing `@autodocs` and some other details. Here is a complete setup for doc-testing in `Julia` with `Documenter.jl`.

Directory structure of `my_module` (from command `tree`, reordered for clarity):

```
.
|____src
| |____my_module.jl
| |____my_functions.jl
|____docs
| |____make.jl
| |____src
| | |____index.md
|____README.md
|____REQUIRE
```

The file `src/my_module.jl` is:

```
module my_module

# export functions you want to call without qualifications
export add_exported

using DataFrames # or any other module

# Include functions
include("my_functions.jl")

end
```

The file `src/my_functions.jl` contains exported and non-exported functions. Note how the doc-test of exported functions has no qualification, and the doc-test of non-exported functions does:

````
"""
    add_exported(x, y)

Dummy function, exported

# Examples
```jldoctest
julia> add_exported(1, 2)
3
```
"""
function add_exported(x::Number, y::Number)
    return x + y
end

"""
    add_not_exported(x, y)

Dummy function, not exported

# Examples
```jldoctest
julia> my_module.add_not_exported(1, 2)
3
```
"""
function add_not_exported(x::Number, y::Number)
    return x + y
end
````

The file `docs/make.jl` is:

```
using Documenter, my_module

makedocs(
    modules = [my_module],
    format = :html,
    sitename = "my_module.jl",
    doctest = true
)
```

The file `docs/src/index.md` contains `using my_module`, which brings exported functions into scope:

````
# Documentation

```@meta
CurrentModule = my_module
DocTestSetup = quote
    using my_module
end
```

```@autodocs
Modules = [my_module]
```
````

The last two files are optional. The file `REQUIRE` serves only for remote installation of package. It contains:

```
julia 0.6.3
DataFrames 0.11.6
```

The file `README.md` contains a description in Markdown:

```
# my_module and its description
```

Finally, change directory to the root of the package, start a Julia session, and type:

```
julia> include("src/my_module.jl");include("docs/make.jl");
Documenter: setting up build directory.
Documenter: expanding markdown templates.
Documenter: building cross-references.
Documenter: running document checks.
 > checking for missing docstrings.
 > running doctests.
 > checking footnote links.
Documenter: populating indices.
Documenter: rendering document.
```

If you change the result of `add` in the doc-test from `3` to any other number, the `Documenter` will show an error and show that it is working.

Comment: This is because doctests are run in sandboxed modules, you need to add `using my_module` as setup-code: https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/doctests/#Setup-Code-1

Comment: @fredrikekre I do have a setup-code in `docs/src/index.md`: `@meta;
CurrentModule = my_module;
DocTestSetup = quote;
    import my_module;
end;` (where semicolons stand for new lines). Do you have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Well, `import` only brings the module name into scope. I suggested `using` which brings in all exported names, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/modules/#Summary-of-module-usage-1

Comment: My mistake, I have `using` and not `import` and I still get the doc-test error `add not defined`. Do you have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: @fredrikekre Your comment pointed in the right direction: I needed to export the function to test in order to use it without qualifications. Thanks!