# Why does Julia Documenter require qualifying functions in doc-tests?

Tags: namespaces, julia, doctest

My doc-tests in Julia require a qualification with the module name, despite calling `using my_module` everywhere. If I do not qualify the functions, I get

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: add not defined
```

Here is the setup that gives this error. The directory structure with `tree` is:

```
.
|____docs
| |____make.jl
| |____src
| | |____index.md
|____src
| |____my_module.jl
```

The file `docs/make.jl` is:

```
using Documenter, my_module

makedocs(
    modules = [my_module],
    format = :html,
    sitename = "my_module.jl",
    doctest = true
)
```

The file `docs/src/index.md` is:

````
# Documentation

```@meta
CurrentModule = my_module
DocTestSetup = quote
    using my_module
end
```

```@autodocs
Modules = [my_module]
```
````

The file `src/my_module.jl` is:

````
module my_module

"""
    add(x, y)

Dummy function

# Examples
```jldoctest
julia> add(1, 2)
3
```
"""
function add(x::Number, y::Number)
    return x + y
end

end
````

If I qualify the doc-test in the `src/my_module.jl` with `my_module.add(1,2)`, then it works fine.

How can I avoid qualifying function names in doc-tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768111/julia-documenter-missing-docstring/51207534#51207534), the problem is that the `add` function is not exported, so it is not brought into scope with `using`. You can add this line near the top of `src/my_module.jl`, after the module declaration:

```
export add
```

And then the doc-testing works.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [setup name block](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/syntax/#@setup-name-block-1)

This is untested, but something like this should work:

````
module my_module

"""
    add(x, y)

Dummy function

# Examples
```@setup abc
import my_module: add
```

```jldoctest abc
julia> add(1, 2)
3
```
"""
function add(x::Number, y::Number)
    return x + y
end

end
````

Comment: This also fails with `> Output Diff: 3ERROR: UndefVarError: add not defined`. I tried other variations such as `using my_module` and `using my_module: add`.